# Dictionaries not working inside a struct SWIFT

Tags: xcode, swift

Why is this not working!?

```
struct ChocolateBox {
    var caramelDelight = []
    caramelDelight["flavor"] = "caramel"
}
```

I tried this without the struct, still doesn't work:

```
var caramelDelight = []
caramelDelight["flavor"] = "caramel"
```

I have to add initial values into the array for it to work, for example:

```
var caramelDelight = ["test":"test"]
caramelDelight["flavor"] = "caramel"
```

Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var caramelDelight = []` doesn't create an empty dictionary.

To create an empty dictionary use `[:]()` and specify the types of the keys and values, example: `var caramelDelight = [String:String]()`.

There's also this alternative syntax: `var caramelDelight: [String:String] = [:]`.

Also to modify the var in your struct you need to create an instance of the struct first:

```
struct ChocolateBox {
    var caramelDelight = [String:String]()
}

var cb = ChocolateBox()
cb.caramelDelight["flavor"] = "caramel"

println(cb.caramelDelight)  // [flavor: caramel]
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also create an initializer for your struct if you need to prepopulate the dictionary:

```
struct ChocolateBox {
    var caramelDelight: [String:String]
    init(dict: [String:String]) {
        self.caramelDelight = dict
    }
}

var cb = ChocolateBox(dict: ["flavor": "caramel"])
```

Of course then you can update the dictionary as usual:

```
cb.caramelDelight["color"] = "brown"

println(cb.caramelDelight)  // [color: brown, flavor: caramel]
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, but how do I initilize a value in the dictionary if I need to create an instance first?

This is my task:
We need to add the first chocolate to our box. Create a stored property named caramelDelight. To this dictionary add a key named flavor that stores a value named caramel to the caramelDelight dictionary to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, however my online coding task is still rejecting this answer, ill just skip it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `caramelDelight` is actually an array, not a dictionary. You can fix that by doing `var caramelDelight: [String:String] = [:]`